# Problem with $.getJSON on IE

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer

i have an application calling a jquery function, like this:

```
$.getJSON('test.php',{dest:2},function(data){
   alert(data);
});
```

Well, the test.php is like this:

`<?php echo json_encode('Test'); ?>`

On FF returns an alert with 'Test', but on IE return an alert without anything.

anyone have any idea?

Comment: `json_encode('Test')` prints `"test"`, which isn't actually valid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved, follow what I did:

replaces the call

```
    $.getJSON('test.php',{dest:2},function(data){
   alert(data);
});
```

for this

```
   $.ajax({
   type: "get",
   url: "test.php",
   data: "dest=2",
   cache:false,
   dataType:'json',
   success: function(data){
     alert(data)
   }
 });
```

like this works on IE and FF

Answer (score 2):

Add mime-type to your php headers. IE does not get it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing content-type application/json as your header.

Add this, before the echo:
`header('Content-type: application/json');`

Answer (score 2):

A JSON document must consist of an array or an object.

If you give `json_encode` a string, then PHP will output a string, which is not a valid JSON document.

You are probably running into differences between the ability of the different JSON parsers used in different browsers to error recover.

Comment: solved, follow what I did:

replaces the call $.getJSON('test.php',{dest:2},function(data){
   alert(data);
});
  for this